# serve files to safari using ashx

Tags: .net, file-upload, ashx

I use an ashx to serve files to the client, like so:

```
  Dim fileGuid = context.Request("fileguid")
  Dim fileName = context.Request("filename")
  Dim area = context.Request("area")
  Dim contentType As String = "application/octet-stream"
  Dim innerFilePath = FilePath(context, fileGuid)

  If File.Exists(innerFilePath) Then
    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=""" + fileName + "")
    context.Response.ContentType = contentType
    context.Response.ClearContent()
    context.Response.WriteFile(innerFilePath)
  End If
```

This works perfectly in all browsers but safari. In safari the file is served but with a file name of upload.ashx.pdf

I've tried changing the mime type to `application/pdf` and testing with a pdf file but no joy.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The filename was not fully enclosed in speech marks. I changed to:

```
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=""" + fileName + """")
```